# If taxonomy exists then to show some code

Tags: custom-taxonomy

I want to insert following custom code in single.php
can I set condition that if specific taxonomy exist then show and work this code otherwise not;

```
<div id="archivebox"> All courses in<?php echo get_the_term_list($post->ID,'country', ' ', ' ', '' ) ; ?><br>All courses in<?php echo get_the_term_list($post->ID,'institute', ' ', ' ', '' ) ; ?><br>All <?php echo get_the_term_list($post->ID,'subject', ' ', ' ', '', '' ) ; ?> courses worldwide<br>All<?php echo get_the_term_list($post->ID,'qualification', ' ', ' ', '' ) ; ?> courses worldwide<br>Alphabetical List: <?php echo get_the_term_list($post->ID,'alphabetical', ' ', ' ', '' ) ; ?> worldwide</div>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to check for the *existence* of a taxonomy, use [`taxonomy_exists( $taxonomy )`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/taxonomy_exists):

```
<?php
if(taxonomy_exists('country')){
     echo 'All courses in' . get_the_term_list($post->ID,'country', ' ', ' ', '' );
}
?>
```

etc...

#### Edit

If, instead of checking for the *existence* of a taxonomy, you want to check if the *current post belongs* to a taxonomy, use [`get_the_term_list( $post->ID, $taxonomy )`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_term_list):

```
<?php
if( false != get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'country' ) ) {
     echo 'All courses in' . get_the_term_list($post->ID,'country', ' ', ' ', '' );
}
?>
```

Comment: I have tried it, it gives following error. HTTP Error 500 (Internal Server Error): An unexpected condition was encountered while the server was attempting to fulfil the request.

Comment: I fixed the PHP syntax in the answer, but, really: code snippets should never be treated as blind copy-and-paste material. Did you not check for syntax errors yourself, before pushing this code snippet live?

Comment: I added ?> already but it's giving error. I am doing my same work with custom post type but now want to combine in post so need this code. Thanks

Comment: Thank you sir. Quite fine. is there a way, if post is not related to that taxonomy then "All courses in" should also not appear?

Comment: @Ahmad "*is there a way, if post is not related to that taxonomy then "All courses in" should also not appear?*" - yes, but you should **edit your question** to add this additional condition; then we can add it to the answer.

Comment: Or you can ask it as another question =p

Answer (score 1):

To avoid [duplicate post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/46555/insert-conditional-code-in-single-php-file/) I'll answer here:

```
<?php
$my_terms = array('country', 'region', 'city');
$terms_obj =  wp_get_object_terms($post->ID, $my_terms);
if( !empty($terms_obj) ) {
    if( !is_wp_error( $terms_obj ) ) {
        echo '<div id="archivebox">All courses in ';
        foreach($terms_obj as $term) {
            foreach($my_terms as $my_term) {
                echo '<a href="'.get_term_link($term->slug, $my_term).'">'.$term->name.'</a> ';
            }
        }
        echo '</div>';
    }
}
?>
```

Edited according comments below.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Maxoud . What if I want to include more terms along with 'country' or how to include php file with condition to if_taxonomy_exists. In that case, I can include as many terms required.

Comment: @Ahmad: I've edited the code above. Not tested though.